# Unable to add all columns entered on phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have created a web page where my customers will be able to enter details of all items there return back to my store. I have created in such a way that, 1 customer can enter his personal details once but can add any number of items he is returning. I have created a "add more" button to do this job. But when I am testing my site, database is only taking the last item entered and is not storing previous items.

```
<script> $(function () {
    $('input.more').on('click', function () {
    var $table = $('#input_fields');
    var $tr = $table.find('tr').eq(0).clone();
    $tr.appendTo($table).find('input').val('');
    });
});
</script>

 <tr>
        <td width="33%"><label class="description" for="element_20">Manufacturer, Model, Serial # </label>
         </td>
        <td width="33%"><label class="description" for="element_10">Tag Number (If Any) </label>
        </td>
        <td width="33%"><label class="description" for="element_4">Item Description </label>
    </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <table id="input_fields" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4">
      <tr>
        <td width="33%"><input id="element_20" name="model" class="element text large" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php if($action != "add") echo $row["model"]; ?>"/></td>
        <td width="33%"><input id="element_10" name="tag" class="element text large" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php if($action != "add") echo $row["tag"]; ?>"/></td>
        <td width="33%"><input name="itemdesc" type="text" class="element text large" id="element_4" value="<?php if($action != "add") echo $row["itemdesc"]; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
<input class="more" type="button" value="Add more" name="addmore"/>       

<ul>
 <li class="buttons">
        <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

In this, when Customer enters a item details and then clicks add more and enter other item details. Only the last enter item details are getting stored. But I want all items to be stored and displayed on DB.

Comment: if the name of the input tags are the same when u click add more, use array `name="model[]"` do the same for all the names and in the php file use for loop to extract the values of each array cell

Answer (score 0):

You end up posting only a single model/tag/text to the server because you have the same `name` property for each copy of the input elements. When PHP tries to map the posted data to `$_POST` it will only map to a single model/tag/itemdesc key in `$_POST` because the input names are the same.

The easiest way to resolve this is to use array access notation in your input names like `model[]`, `tag[]`, `itemdesc[]`.  This will allow PHP to assemble an array of values for each model/tag/itemdesc key in `$_POST`.

Try this.  Do a `var_dump($_POST)` at the beginning of your script before changing your HTML code. Run a multi-item test case and look at the dumped value.

Then change to use array access notation in your HTML and see the difference the `var_dump()` gives.